# How to do an action in periodic intervals in java?

Tags: java, loops, timer

Is there any way of creating a loop that would do the task every 3 secs without using a sleep function

For eg:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(new Date());
        Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But the problem while using sleep function is that, it just freezes the program.

> The main idea of this loop is to get a sync  with mysql database
>   (online).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `java.util.TimerTask`

```
java.util.Timer t = new java.util.Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("This will run every 5 seconds");

            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
```

If you are using a GUI, you can use the `javax.swing.Timer`, example:

```
int delay = 5000; //milliseconds
  ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          System.out.println("This will run every 5 seconds");
      }
  };
  new javax.swing.Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Some info about the difference between `java.util.Timer` and `java.swing.Timer`:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html

> Both it and javax.swing.Timer provide the same basic functionality,
>   but java.util.Timer is more general and has more features. The
>   javax.swing.Timer has two features that can make it a little easier to
>   use with GUIs. First, its event handling metaphor is familiar to GUI
>   programmers and can make dealing with the event-dispatching thread a
>   bit simpler. Second, its automatic thread sharing means that you don't
>   have to take special steps to avoid spawning too many threads.
>   Instead, your timer uses the same thread used to make cursors blink,
>   tool tips appear, and so on.

Comment: *"This will run every 3 seconds"* - No, it won't ;) and this also assumes that the user isn't using some kind of GUI framework

Comment: sysout fixed :) @MadProgrammer why you say that it assumes the user isn't using any GUI framework? is this why I didn't suggest to use `javax.swing.Timer`?

Comment: There's no context to the question.  If the OP is using Swing (for example), then is might not be a good idea.  It is still a valid answer given the context, but I'd (personally) state that this assumes that the OP isn't using a GUI - IMHO

Comment: The programe is a GUI. @fmodos: It worked fine for me. But can you simplify the code for netbeans environment :)

Comment: @user2471839 I am not sure what you mean by 'simplify the code for netbeans', this code doesn't use any third party library... so you just need to copy it into your code, anyway I will update the answer with an example of coding using the javax.swing.Timer as this is one GUI.

Comment: @fmodos can you  help me out with this part: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397442/how-to-check-if-a-jframe-is-opened

Comment: @user2471839 no, I haven't coded GUI applications for a while... maybe someone else with more experience into that can help you.

Comment: @fmodos  
i need the following statement to execute instead of :
 System.out.println("This will run every 5 seconds");

 textarea.append("This will run every 5 seconds\n");

But the problem is, i cannot use the textarea because it is not created before. can you give me a suggestion to this problem

Comment: @user2471839 You may find `SwingWorker` more suited to the task

Answer (score 4):

You may use one of the implementation of [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) if you are Ok to move logic which you want to execute repeatedly inside a thread.

Here is example from the link:

```
 import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.*;
 class BeeperControl {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    public void beepForAnHour() {
        final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
                public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
            };
        final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
        scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
                public void run() { beeperHandle.cancel(true); }
            }, 60 * 60, SECONDS);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using some kind of UI?

There are at least two timers available in Java;

- [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)
- [`java.util.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Which should be capable of achieving what you want

There are also 3rd party libraries that might help as well