# How to check if a jframe is opened?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog, jtabbedpane

My code below create a new array and sends it to chat(jFrame).

```
String info1[]=new String[3];
 // username , userid , userid2 are variables
 info1[0]=username4;
 info1[1]=""+userid;
 info1[2]=""+userid2;

 chat.main(info1);
```

But i need to modify this code to work such a way that it ,  if the chat jframe was opened,
then dont open a new jFrame .But instead open a new tab in chat jframe . The code for chat frame is :

```
private void formWindowActivated(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {       
  JScrollPane panel2 = new JScrollPane();
  JTextArea ta=new JTextArea("");
  ta.setColumns(30);
  ta.setRows(19);
  panel2.setViewportView(ta);
  jTabbedPane1.add("Hello", panel2);   
}
```

Comment: I swear to god I saw this same question earlier today. Have you tried searching this?

Comment: See also - [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if you shouldn't be using JDialogs instead of JFrames, if the window is dependent on another window.

A solution is to use a class field to hold a reference to the window (JFrame or JDialog) and checking if it is null or visible, and if so, then lazily create/open the window,

```
public void newChat(User user) {
  if (chatWindow == null) {
    // create chatWindow in a lazy fashion
    chatWindow = new JDialog(myMainFrame, "Chat", /* modality type */);
    // ...  set up the chat window dialog
  }

  chatWindow.setVisible(true);
  addTabWithUser(user);
}
```

but that's about all I can say based on the information provided. If you need more specific help, then you will need to provide more information.

Comment: Thank you for giving me the idea of JDialog.

Answer (score 1):

If using JFrames it can be simply done like this:

```
if (Frame1.component != null) {
   Frame1 is opened
} else if (Frame2.component == null) {
   Frame2 is closed
}
```

Component ex.JTextField, JComboBox etc.

Comment: getting "error: component has private access in Container"